# Ajax overlay not showing during ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, overlay, modal-dialog

```
$("#keywordSearchSubmit").on("click", function()
{
    showOverlay();
    var searchString = $("#search-results-form-query").val();
    var manResult = $.ajax({
        url: "Order?Page=storeSearchKeyword",
        data: "searchString="+searchString,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
    $("#cart-product-list").empty();
    $("#cart-product-list").append(manResult);
    hideOverlay();
});

function showOverlay()
{
//alert('a');
 $("#overlay").css("display","block");
//document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'block';
}

function hideOverlay()
{
//alert('b');
$("#overlay").css({"display":"none"});
//document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = 'none';
}
```

I've got the above Javascript so that an overlay appears whilst the ajax call is being performed.
The below is the HTML for the overlay.

```
<div id=\"overlay\" style=\"display:none;\">
<div style=\"display:block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top:15%\" class=\"bubblingG\">
<span id=\"bubblingG_1\"></span><span id=\"bubblingG_2\"></span><span id=\"bubblingG_3\">
</span></div></div>
```

The overlay will not show no matter which variety of the above javascript I use:

document.getElement...
$("#overlay")...

The only time the overlay shows up is when I add alert boxes. Once I click 'ok' in the alert box the overlay will appear.

I've tried:

```
$("#overlay").trigger("create");
```

But no success. I know that I can use jQuery start and complete rather than calling the methods like above but it will still only show when I use alerts before the overlay is shown.

The request takes around 5 seconds to process on the server end so the overlay should definitely show.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's related to the synchronous AJAX call (cf. [jQuery documentation about AJAX settings)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).  I'd try modifying your code to be something like

```
showOverlay();
var searchString = $("#search-results-form-query").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "Order?Page=storeSearchKeyword",
    data: "searchString="+searchString,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var manResult = jqXHR.responseText;
        $("#cart-product-list").empty();
        $("#cart-product-list").append(manResult);
        hideOverlay();
    }
});
```